# Access the most recent data near rundate from access

Tags: c++, sql, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on retrieving records from access db through sql query. The origina query retrieves the most recent date data. But if i want to run the tool for example 3/3/2012 it still taking the most recent data. But i need the data which is either equal to date 3/3/2012 or the date close to 3/3/2012 but not exceeding the date. For example if 3/3/2012 is not available and 3/2/2012 is available in the db it should pick that date. The modified query is shown below. It gives the exception of reserved word misspelling or puctuation mistake.. etc. Can you please help me with query. In the query trundate is input from my program. My query is now:

CString sel = "SELECT I.ProductType, I.Spread, I.DateUpdated FROM MortgageRateSpreads I,(select ProductType, MAX(DateUpdated) AS DateUpdated1";
        sel +=  "where DateUpdated <=" ;
        sel += tRunDate.Format("{ts '%Y-%m-%d'  }");

CRecordset set(&pdatabase);

```
    try
    {

        double  val;
        CDBVariant var;

        if (set.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, sel/*, CRecordset::readOnly*/)) 
        {
            m_Log->Log("recordset is open");
            while (!set.IsEOF())
```

MY Sel is:

```
sel "SELECT I.ProductType, I.Spd, I.DateUpdated FROM MRSpds I,(select ProductType, MAX(DateUpdated) AS DateUpdated1where DateUpdated <={ts '2012-02-08'  } FROM MRSpds GROUP BY ProductType) T WHERE I.ProductType = T.ProductType AND I.DateUpdated =T.DateUpdated1"
```

Thank You

```
            {
```

Comment: Can you show us what sel contains just before you execute the query. It is easier to provide feedback when we can see the final SQL statement. I don't think the value following TOP goes in brackets for msaccess SQL. Should be TOP 1 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think ms access likes # symbols around dates. DateUpdated<=#3-3-2012#
in the sel += "where..." you need a space such as sel += " where ..."
also the date string in the SQL statement should look like
DateUpdated <= #3/3/2012#

Also, your nested select statement seems to have the from clause following the where clause. I think it should be something like

> (select ProductType, MAX(DateUpdated) AS DateUpdated1  FROM MRSpds where DateUpdated <= #2012-02-08# GROUP BY ProductType) T

Comment: No, it doesn't work, i have tried. The time format is working in the other program. I'll try again with hardcoding the format you have given. By the way in access the date fromat is like this: 3/3/2012Thank You

Comment: The error was reserved word or argument is misspelled or punctuation is wrong

Comment: Was that error occurring with TOP (1) in the SQL statement. If so, try TOP 1 without the brackets

Comment: Yeah, it's occuring with TOP(1) also. Thank You